# Asp.net GridView with Bootstrap dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, html-lists

I'm currently helping out a friend with his thesis and I've run into something that I can't seem to figure out. I've got a couple of grid views that get populated by a web service. The thing that I want to do is to display the records as a list and have a column that will contain a dropdown list of command that can be issued to the webservice for that particular row in the gridview however I can't seem to figure out how to connect the dropdown list commands with the gridview rows.

I don't have a lot of ASP.NET experience behind me and searching and finding yielded me with little that I currently understand or use to figure my way into this.

The code is the following:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <asp:GridView ID="gvData1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" PageSize="30" CssClass="float:left">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-CssClass="col-md-2" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name">
         <ItemStyle Font-Bold="True" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Ip Address" HeaderText="IP" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="SID" HeaderText="SID" />
      <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Status" HeaderText="Status">
         <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      </asp:ImageField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Commands">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul id="ddgv1" class="dropdown-menu" runat="server">
               <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Oracle Options</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" id="1" aria-valuetext="Shutdown" >Shutdown Instance</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" id="2" aria-valuetext="STARTUP">Startup Intance</a></li>
               <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
               <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Service Options</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" id="3" aria-valuetext="start">Start Service</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" id="4" aria-valuetext="stop">Stop Service</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Comment: even if you make it work, is not going to save the results when you change the dropdown menu because you use now the view, not the edit... is not so simple to make it all this work... you need a programmer that knows and make it work with a lot of experience...

Comment: I only need it to send the row data on dropdown value select this isn't being saved in database it should only raise a method.

Comment: "I only need"... yes you only need that - this is complicate... make it first work with a normal dropdown list, to see that is not so easy even then....

Comment: Isn't there a way to use an onselect or something and then in the code behind to find the row that sender is referring to?

Comment: Yes exist the onselect... but is not work as you believe inside a GridView... also you can have an auto post back... and what do you post back ??? not this is not the way of gridview. Start by using a normal dropdon list box, and then see how difficult is that... and if you make that work, then you can convert it to bootstrap